# Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory when calling Apache CXF Client in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf, pom.xml

I'm trying to use a service in my spring boot application. This exact client works fine in netbeans and an older project using spring 3 MVC but when I try to call the same method I get `javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory`.

I searched a lot and tried different answer but no luck! these are some of question on stackoverflow that I tried:

[CXF web service client: "Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114945/cxf-web-service-client-cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory)

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory when deploying on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035304/java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory-when-deployin)

[Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590793/cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory)

[Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory when calling Apache CXF Client from Plain Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553491/cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory-when-calling-apache-cxf-client-from-plain)

Although passing a VM Option for allowing less secure parsers wasn't a solution for me I tried that. When I added the `-Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser=1` the first line of code does not throw the specified exception but on second line when I try to get the port a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: QUALIFIED` will be thrown!

Code for calling service:

```
MessageRelayService messageRelayService = new MessageRelayService();
MessageRelay msgService = messageRelayService.getMessageRelayPort();

CountResult countResult = msgService.getReceivedMessageCount(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

My pom(some parts were omitted for brevity):

```
<properties>
    ...
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <cxf.version>3.0.0</cxf.version>
    <swagger.version>2.6.0</swagger.version>
    <purchase.version>1.2.4</purchase.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Camden.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    ...
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    .
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
</dependencies>
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to add the following dependency: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.12</version>
</dependency> ? See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html

Comment: Done it and no luck! But if I'm not mistaken this is for serving service I'm trying to use from an endpoint.

Comment: Although not reporting the same problem, see if this gives you any hint: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201706.mbox/%3C1498020844227-5781362.post@n5.nabble.com%3E. Try not to inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent. Add the dependencies explicitly. Maybe you are having conflicting versions on dependencies

Comment: Thank @pringi but woodstux dependency removed after version 3 of cfx

Comment: I'll try to add dependencies explicitly and get back to you with the results thanks

Comment: Thanks @pringi with your kind help I finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search and trying all kinds of things with help of @pringi I returned back to my pom and found out the problem so I thought to write an answer maybe it'll help somebody someday!

The problem was that I had some dependencies in my pom that weren't needed and they could be removed and they conflicted with cxf! So I removed these dependencies and voila!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks To All!